# Is there a way to control the percentages of random instances?

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, instances

I am looking to randomly instance objects onto a plane using Geometry nodes and Ive got that working fine.  But I want to be able to control the proportion of the different instances.  For example if I have three objects that are being randomly instanced can I make it so that I can set one of them to be 80% and the others 10% each (or some other way that will have a similar effect).

Comment: You may take a look as well onto this thread: [Select a subset of points in geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261622/select-a-subset-of-points-in-geometry-nodes)

Answer (score 1):

You should put an ID in the instance on point node. In your example, you can plug a random boolean and set probability to 0.9. You can also use switch nodes to set different ids:

[image]