# How to control the "Pick Instance" slot on an "Instances on Points" node

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I am scattering a collection of objects on a mesh through the `Instances on Points` node using Geometry Nodes. The `Collection Info` node is going into the `Instance` slot on the `Instances on Points` node. The checkbox for `Pick Instance` is turned on.

**How would I be able to control how much of each instance is being 'picked'?**

Answer (score 0):

The instances of a collection are selected according to the order in which they are stored in the collection.

This order is determined by the name of the object (alphabetical sorting).

So if you have the following objects, they have the following index

| Name | Index |
| --- | --- |
| Cube | 0 |
| Cube.001 | 1 |
| Cube.002 | 2 |

If you have now activated *Pick Instances* and use a value at *Instance Index*, always the object with the corresponding index from your collection will be used.

So to be able to selectively or with a certain probability use objects from your collection, you would have to pass the corresponding values to the *Instance Index* input.

[image]

For example, if a value is passed that exceeds the number of objects in your collection, the count starts again at $0$, so your first object is selected.

This is illustrated in the following table:

| Instance Index | Name | Object Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Cube | 0 |
| 1 | Cube.001 | 1 |
| 2 | Cube.002 | 2 |
| 3 | Cube | 0 |
| 4 | Cube.001 | 1 |
| 5 | Cube.002 | 2 |

Comment: I believe, OP asked about a slightly different thing, like in this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261922/is-there-a-way-to-control-the-percentages-of-random-instances?rq=1

Comment: @Crantisz Ah, OK, you might be right! I'll leave the answer anyway ...maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: Crantisz answered my question. 

Comment: @Crantisz Sorry, I didn't mean to diminish the quality of your existing answer by choosing another duplicate as you suggested initially. I just wanted to target as a moderator the answer that explained the topic in more detail. Thank you for your understanding.