# How to move a certain number of separated faces to the same number of points based on the center coordinates of the face?

Tags: geometry-nodes

As the title says, I want to move a certain number of separated faces to the same number of points based on the center coordinates of the face.

In the process of solving the above problem, I have thought about handling it through the distribute on points node, but the instance cannot meet my actual work scenario, because the node I want to implement has to act on surfaces of different sizes.
In the uploaded blender file, the model (ToApplyGM_Mesh) that actually needs to be applied is shown.

The problem I currently encounter is that I can move these surfaces to the corresponding points, but I guess that because of the field, the control points of these surfaces are reduced to one point.
How can I keep the size of the surface unchanged, rotate it randomly, and move it to the position of the corresponding point of the shadow?

Blender file [image]

Orginal face [image]
To move points [image]
Current moved result [image]
To apply on real surfaces mesh [image]
GeometryNode view [image]

ps: In the uploaded file, nodes involving randomly selected points are derived from [enter link description here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261622/select-a-subset-of-points-in-geometry-nodes), thank you André Zmuda’s solution